# Another minor memory C++ question

Tags: c++, memory

```
int main() {


  char **k;
  char *s ="abc"; 
  char *b ="def";    

  k = &s;
  k++;
  k = &b;
  cout<<*(k - 1)<<endl; // nothing but newline. Shouldn't I get "abc"? 
  //EDIT: corrected a typo should be *(k - 1)  
}
```

I got nothing but a `newline` from `cout`. When I looked at the behavior of char* I get the impression that since I have the address of of the first character I could use char* like an array, which is true. However, for char** this behavior seems to be totally different, when I tried k++ it doesn't seem to behave like an array. Why is that?

Also when I tried (K + 1) = &b; I got an error, why couldn't I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k` is a pointer to a pointer to a char, so when you advance it, it does not walk down the string as you're expecting it to. Instead, it now points to the `char *` that is located adjacent to the one it was pointing to. In your case there is none, so you're de-referencing a random memory location when you print the value of `*(k - 1)`.

```
(K + 1) = &b;
```

The above is an error because you must have an l-value on the left side of an assignment, it cannot be a temporary expression (r-value).

**EDIT:**
Here's an example that'll hopefully be easier to follow than reading about the mistake you've made.

```
int main()
{
  char **k;
  char *s[2] = {"abc", "qwerty"};

  k = &s[0];
  std::cout << *(k + 1) << std::endl; // prints "qwerty"

  k++;
  std::cout << *(k - 1) << std::endl; // prints "abc"

  std::cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it now points to the char * that is located adjacent to the one it was pointing to." Since I have advanced k with k++, shouldn't (k - 1) be k?

Comment: It would've been, except you made this assignment in between: `k = &b;`. Now k points to the address of b, so when you do `k-1` it is pointing to a `char *` located right before b (there isn't one), so you get garbage when you print it (or it'll crash your program).

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't point it to an array, `*(k-1)` is actually accessing indeterminate memory and producing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some example values to your code. Note, I just made them up for illustrative purposes!  I'll assume a 32-bit (4-byte) pointer.

```
char **k;        /* pointer @ 0x1000 */
char *s = "abc"; /* four bytes @ 0x2004 = "abc", pointer @ 0x1020 = 0x2004 */
char *b = "def"; /* four bytes @ 0x2000 = "def", pointer @ 0x1010 = 0x2000 */

k = &s;  /* pointer @ 0x1000 now = 0x1020 */
k++;     /* pointer @ 0x1000 now = 0x1024 (one char* [4 bytes] more) */
k = &b;  /* pointer @ 0x1000 now = 0x1010 */
cout<<*(k - 1)<<endl; /* k-1 = 0x100C ... *(k-1) = ??? */
```

**EDIT** fixed up mistakes in the `k = &...` lines, added an explicit 32-bit pointer size.

Comment: You've got two variables at `0x1000`, and also `k-1` isn't 0x1FFF, it's `&b` - `sizeof (char*)`.  All the other lines are totally wrong too.  `k = &s` uses the address of `s`, not the address `s` is pointing to, ditto `k = &b`.  `k++` adds in `sizeof (char*)`.

Comment: @Ben you're right, sorry, I rushed the k=&foo bit.  And I probably shouldn't have used 8-bit pointers.  Edited.

Comment: That's much better, although `k-1` would be `0x100C`.